# How to pass input values in python executable file?

Tags: python, command-line, attributes, parameter-passing, exe

Some times, when we call an .exe file in command prompt, we also pass some parameters or attributes in one command. which are mostly following hyphen "**--**" or simply following a space. For example, `app.exe parameters` or `app.exe --parameter="value"`. How we can create such type type of exe files in python.

For this I created a python file "file.py" which has following code :

```
variable = input()
print("You have entered "+variable)
```

After exporting it into "file.exe" I tried to call it as :`file.exe "any_text` But it doesn't work but I try to call it as :`file.exe --variable="any_text"`. but still not worked.
Let me know how to create such type of .exe files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the *getopt* module

Comment: Use argv not input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating an executable file in Python that which accepts command-line arguments, better to use the `argparse` module.

***Example:***

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--variable', help='Input variable')

args = parser.parse_args()

print("You have entered " + args.variable)
```

Then, when run the script, you can pass in the ***value*** of the `"--variable"` argument such as:

```
file.exe --variable any_text
```